# Python: PyEnchant and 64 bit Python

Tags: python, text-processing, pyenchant

I am doing text processing. I need the PyEnchant library for verifying if a particular word in the text is a valid English word. However, it's only available for the 32 bit installation of Python. I need the 64 bit Python for handling memory issues with large text files.

Is there a way that I can install PyEnchant for the 64-bit Python? If not, what other library can I use to accomplish the similar task? I looked into the NLTK's wordnet but read that the functionality is not as good as PyEnchant.

Comment: What platform, and what method are you using to try to install it?

Comment: We usually use `python setup.py install` like normal...

Comment: I did "easy_install pyenchant" and it didn't install it. I am trying to install it for windows XP, with python 2.7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you find it absolutely essential to have PyEnchant, you could download the Source code [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.6.tar.gz#md5=9f5acfd87d04432bf8df5f9710a17358) and then manually install it by putting it in whatever directory you prefer and then running

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/dir')
```

This should work, and should be compatible with people who installed it normally.

Comment: Do you know if PyEnchant runs with Python version 3.4?

Comment: @Pilie :No, it does not. While **I** would suggest to make your own version, you could upgrade it(maybe) to 3.4. For details, check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) page out, or, if necessary, do it yourself(if you must). PS:Sorry about taking so long to reply.

Comment: Have you or anyone made the Windows 10 64 bit compatible enchant version that can run on Python 3.4?